# Multithreading in C on kernel level

Tags: c, multithreading

In my knowledge `C language` does not have the direct explicit framework for `multithreading` like `Java`, then how kernel level programs, such as the system drivers and operating system function are `multithreaded` while they are written in `C`? How the `multithreading` is supported at lower level.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But take a step back and you'll realize that you're asking the wrong question. Most of the libraries in C map to kernel level functions. So in that sense, when you're in the kernel, you really have nothing. Everything is bare metal at some point.

Comment: What do you mean by kernel level programs?  A kernel thread?

Comment: C doesn't *disallow* multithreading, it just doesn't require it as part of the language definition. But there's nothing to stop someone from adding a multithreading library on top of C (so long as they play by all the other rules). One result of this, though, is that the library calls to use multithreading may look different on different platforms - eg unix vs windows.

Comment: The latest C standard, C11, adds language support for threading.

Comment: Please don't downvote or comment if you don't understand the question. I was asking about  the older versions of C language.

Comment: @PawanSharma You make a statement that C doesn't allow multithreading, which is incorrect in any version of the standard. It is also unclear what you mean with "kernel level programs". So your whole question consists of one incorrect statement and one unclear one, you should edit the question to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreading is an abstraction.  As is, you can't execute more instructions than the number of cores (with exceptions to a certain extent).  Instead, it's achieved through scheduling and descheduling threads and/or processes.

Basically to get something that looks like its multithreaded, you want to be able to track two different instruction pointers and share memory.  In the kernel, you're just going down an level of abstraction.